# Temporary dishwasher drain without sink, is this ok?

Tags: drain, dishwasher

Remodelling kitchen. Our counter and sink will be installed in about a month. Until then, I wanted to have the dishwasher hooked up. I did this, but I’m not sure if this is sound. After doing it, I started worrying that the p-trap might get siphoned, or a vacuum might prevent proper draining, since there’s no sink to provide air.[image]

Comment: that will not work as is, you need a vent line

Comment: Agreed; there needs to be some form of vacuum break here. The sink drain normally provides that.

Comment: Yeah I disconnected the dishwasher pipe and water rushed out of it. I replaced it with a setup that has a pipe going up to simulate the sink, and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Make sure the dishwasher drain tube goes up first and is secured at counter height before it goes down to the trap (a "high loop").

Comment: Yeah, that’s why it’s coming down from the top.

Comment: How did you fasten your pipes and fittings together?

Comment: ABS cement and a flexible coupling